# Remove Items from list?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have a listview with an adapter attached to it and an arraylist:

```
   contactArrayList= new ArrayList<String>();
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contactArrayList);
        listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

My listview always contains the contents of my arraylist, because after modifying the arraylist, I always call             `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. Now, how can I let the user remove a value from the ListView, and also remove it from my array? I know how to let the user delete an item from a listview, but now I want to remove the String that coresponds to that item in my ArrayList as well. How can I do that?

Comment: Just remove rhe item from the arraylist.

Comment: show the code you have now for deleting

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi But how will I know which item they are removing

Comment: It dépends on how you want to implement it. Look for onitemclick or onlongitemclick...

Answer (score 0):

If i undestand correctly i need just to remove the item from your ArrayList.

```
contactArrayList.remove(positionToRemove);
```

Comment: How will I know which they are removing

Comment: How exactly they removes item from list? Is there some swype to delete, OnLongClick or onContextItemSelect?